# HTTP 400 Bad Request using https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageToken=SomePageToken

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

Here is a powershell code snippet I am using when I get the error:

Calling code:

```
$global:NextPage = $null

GetCourses  # Calls a function to get the first 500 rows

Do {
    GetNextCourses $global:NextPage  # Get next 500 rows using Page Token
} Until ($global:NextPage -eq $null)

The function where I always get an error.  Always at a different rowset / Page Token:

function GetNextCourses ($next) {

$retrycount = 0
$completed = $false
[int]$retries = 5 
[int]$secondsDelay = 10

while (-not $completed) {
    Try{   
        $list_courses_url = "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses?pageToken=" + $next
        $auth = "Bearer " + $tokens.access_token
        $headers = @{ "Authorization" = $auth }   
        $global:response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $list_courses_url -Method GET -headers $headers -ErrorAction Stop -UseBasicParsing
        if ($global:response.StatusCode -eq 200) {
            $completed = $true
        }
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
        if ($retrycount -ge $retries) {
            $global:Failure = $_.Exception.Response
            Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
            throw
        } else {
            $secondsDelay = $secondsDelay * 2
            Start-Sleep $secondsDelay
            $retrycount++
            $global:Failure = $_.Exception.Response
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 400) {
                Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
                GetTokens   
            }
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 401) {
                GetTokens   
            }
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 403) {
                GetTokens   
            }
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 404) {
                Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
                return
            }
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 429) {
                Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
                Write-Host "....... Waiting ........"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 600 # Additional wait for Resource Exhausted
            }
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 500) {
                Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
                Write-Host "....... Waiting ........"
            }
            if ($global:Failure.StatusCode.Value__ -eq 503) {
                Write-Host $global:Failure.StatusDescription
                Write-Host "....... Waiting ........"
            }
        }
    }
}

$rows = $global:response | ConvertFrom-Json 

$global:NextPage = $rows.nextPageToken
```

.......   # More code
.......   # More code

I have ran this code many times getting 400 bad request errors always at different Page Tokens so I know the code works right for X rows.  We have thousands of courses at Greenville County Schools and the code always runs for several hours before getting the 400 bad request.  After I get the 400 error code getting a new token or waiting x amount of seconds does not work. I have tried waiting x seconds before trying to use a new page token and this does not work.  I would think that all of the web requests should be valid requests since I am using the same code only a different Page Token that is supplied by the previous request.

Pulling my hair out for weeks!  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  I have already read this documentation.  I am not modifying any courses.  I am simply trying to get a list of courses.  When I get the 400 error that you are speaking of I can not continue getting the next 500 rows of courses because the Next Page token is not valid for the next 500 rows.  Unless I have a logic problem in the above powershell code there is no way to continue after trapping the error.  If I do have a logic problem I would very much appreciate any help on figuring that out.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I get more information on which courses have reached some limit and exactly why when I can not get a complete list of courses?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Request.Errors), the Classroom API returns a `FAILED_PRECONDITION (HTTP 400)` error when the requested action is not permitted because of some current state.

> - `CourseMemberLimitReached` indicates that the requested action would exceed the maximum allowed number of course members.
> - `CourseNotModifiable` indicates that the relevant course is in a state that doesn't allow its properties to be modified.
> - `CourseTeacherLimitReached` indicates that the requested action would exceed the maximum allowed number of course teachers.
> - `UserGroupsMembershipLimitReached` indicates that the requested user is already a member of the maximum allowed number of groups.
> - `AttachmentNotVisible` indicates that one or more attachments specified are not visible to the user, are not of the requested type, or do not exist.